# Python: To avoid a TypeError do I need to check if there is a list in a dictionary, then check if that list holds the item?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have several dictionaries.  Sometimes they have with the key `thing` whose value is a dictionary.

Sometimes that dictionary has the key `anotherthing` whose value is a string which could be empty.  So if I want to check the value of `anotherthing` to see if A. The key actually exists and B. the value evaluates to something, I need to use three `if` statements (because any one of the keys could not exist)?

```
    if 'thing' in dictionary_one:
        if 'anotherthing' in dictionary_one['thing']:
            val = dictionary_one['thing']['anotherthing'] 
              if val:
                    # Do something with value
```

In other languages a value will just evaluate to `None` is there a way around this other than using a `Try...Except`?

Comment: What's wrong with `try ... except`?  I believe that's actually the most Pythonic way to do it.

Comment: Please share a test input, expected output and your output. Share some more code also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could chain the lookup with `dict.get()`:

```
val = dictionary_one.get('thing', {}).get('anotherthing')
if val:
```

Comment: This will search all subkeys of the main dictionary?

Comment: It'll take a *specific* key. It'll return either `dictionary_one['thing']` or an empty dictionary, and from that result take the `'anotherthing'` key, or `None`.

Comment: In other words, it is the exact functional equivalent of what you used in your question.